# Linux command to change xx.xx into xx,xx (for currency)

Tags: linux, command, currency

I live in Holland and currency is stated with a komma (,) instead of a dot (.)
I.e.feeds with 14.95 is interpreted as a number instead of 14,95 in euros

Is there a LINUX command (sed?) which can solve this problem?
So 14.95 is changed into 14,95

I've tried to replace the dot with a komma but the feed has a number of correct dot's which are also replaced

Comment: use gettext and locales.... this is the best way to use the locale related stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sed command replaces '.' between digits with a comma (komma)

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]*\)\.\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\1,\2/'
```

Comment: If there is more than one price on a line you need g. Why don't you use + in stead of *?

Comment: Yes, if there is more than one price, we need g. '+' is not supported in some versions of sed. By using * like this, we can make this more portable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the legitimate full stops are in other fields you could use awk to change only the currency field and ignore any "." in other fields.  Here is an inline example where the currency is in field 2:

```
echo "field1 19.45 field3" | awk '{gsub("\\.",",",$2);print $0}'
```

You can do the same with an input file,

```
awk '{gsub("\\.",",",$2);print $0}' in_file > out_file
```

Comment: Your option from a file didn't work (other option I didn't try)

Comment: Did you change "in_file" for your actual file name?  And did you change $2 to the field number in the file?  What delimiters are you using?  If you need too change it from whitespace you can use `-F"d"` where d is the delimiter. Perhaps we could help more if you could share a line from the file?

Answer (score 0):

If all your entries are in file, you could do

```
cat file | awk -F\. '{print $1","$2}' > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **setlocale**, you just have to use the following at the program entry point (at the beginning of *main()*):

```
#include <locale.h>
...
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    ...
```

(of course, you can use `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "");` to only affect numeric printing)

to get *printf()* and cousins begin printing decimal point in the locale you reside in (of course, if you have it configured in your environment).  See the manpage for full documentation.